# Angular - MdDatepicker not working exactly as expected

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

I'm using two datepickers coming from @angular/material (the first one represents the "FromDate" and the second one represents "ToDate"

I managed to implement it by following instructions provided by Angular Material team on their site but I couldn't find a way to :
- On clicking the input field, the calendar should appear (not just by clicking on the icon)
- Avoid the user to type anything in the input field

For the first problem, nothing is written about this use case on their site, I even tried to play with `focus` property but didn't work.
For the second problem, the only way I found is to `disable` the input field (but it's not a solution for me)

Here's what I have in my HTML :

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="datepickerFrom" [max]="endDate">
    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="datepickerFrom"></button>
    <md-datepicker #datepickerFrom [startAt]="startDate" (selectedChanged)="onSelectStartDate($event)"></md-datepicker>
</div

<div class="input-group">
     <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="datepickerEnd" [min]="startDate" [disabled]="true" [max]="endDate">
     <button class="input-group-addon" [mdDatepickerToggle]="datepickerEnd"></button>
     <md-datepicker #datepickerEnd [startAt]="startDate" (selectedChanged)="onSelectEndDate($event)"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

To explain some of the attributes provided, if I select a date in the first datepicker (FromDate), then the second datepicker will begin at this date.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `open` method to open `datepicker` dialog on `focus` or `click` in the `input` tag.

To disable keyboard input, add an event handler `(keydown)="false"`

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="datepickerFrom" [max]="endDate" (click)="datepickerFrom.open()" (keydown)="false">
    <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="datepickerFrom"></button>
    <md-datepicker #datepickerFrom [startAt]="startDate" (selectedChanged)="onSelectStartDate($event)"></md-datepicker>
</div

<div class="input-group">
     <input mdInput [mdDatepicker]="datepickerEnd" [min]="startDate" [disabled]="true" [max]="endDate" (click)="datepickerEnd.open()" (keydown)="false">
     <button class="input-group-addon" [mdDatepickerToggle]="datepickerEnd"></button>
     <md-datepicker #datepickerEnd [startAt]="startDate" (selectedChanged)="onSelectEndDate($event)"></md-datepicker>
</div>
```

If you need more reference, you can see this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/sE8hFm7QL2OmfuSQ57yw?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Nehal ;) At first I thought I should use a @ViewChild to do what I want, but I didn't know it could work this way